# my case script should not be case sensitive and want to pass string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/bash

  helpFunc()
{

    echo  "Usage:

    $0 --arg1
    $0 --arg2 filename add/delete/replace "hi how are you"


    $0 --help
    "
}


function fileread()  {
pwd 
echo "Fileread Function"

if [ -f $filename ] 
 then 
    echo "file exists"
    filename=$1
    cat $1
    case "$1" in
                add|ADD)
                        read $1 
                         if [$2 == 'add' ]
                         then 
                          echo $3 >> $1
                          echo "add opeartion completed"
                          fi
                        shift
                        ;;
                delete|DELETE)
                        read $1
                        echo "echo delet string from file"
                        if [$2 == 'delete' ]
                         then 
                          sed '/$3/d' $1
                          echo "add opeartion completed"
                          fi
                        shift
                        ;;
                replace|REPLACE)
                        read $1
                        if [ $4 == 'replace' ]
                         then
                             sed "s/$5/$6/g" "$1" > temp.txt
                             else
                             echo "Error: Cannot read $1"
                              fi
                      shift
                      ;;

                esac
                shift
#   return 0
  else  
    echo "file not exist"
#return 1 

fi
}

while [ $# ]
do
 case "$1" in

  --a)

               if [ -z "$2" ]
               then
                echo "No argument supplied"
                echo "hello" && echo " current process id : $$ "
                else 
                echo -e "no need of sending arguments for --a"
                 helpFunc a;
                 exit 1
                 shift
                fi
                 ;;

    --b)

            if [ $( echo -e $2 | grep -c -E "^-" ) -eq 0 ]
            then
                fileName=$2
                if [ -f "$fileName" ]
                then
                    echo -e "The file is valid"
                    echo "Displaying $2 file..." 
             [ -z $fileName ] && { echo "File name missing"; exit 1; } || cat $fileName
              case "$filename" in
                add|ADD)
                        echo "adding"
                       fileread $3 $4 
                        shift
                        ;;
                delete|DELETE)
                        echo "echo deleting"
                        fileread
                        shift
                        ;;
                replace|REPLACE)
                     echo "replacing"
                       fileread
                       shift
                       ;;

                esac
                else
                    echo -e "please enter the valid file name or location"
                    helpFunc b;
                    exit 1
                    shift
                fi
            fi      


esac

shift

done

exit 0
```

Comment: The votes are stacking up to close your question as "Unclear what you are asking".(Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.) . . . . What is the problem? and please fix the spacing and indenting  in your post. AND do  you really need ~50 lines of code to illustrate your problem?  Please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

function file read should ignore the case inputs like ADD/add , delete/Delete etc.. and perform operations if i give the cmd line arguments and values and it should validate case sensitivity, file existence and path of the file

./script.sh -a -b /etc/opt/test.txt ADD "hi how are you" delete "i am fine" REPLACE "hi " "hey"